# Why my ListView entry is clickable?

Tags: android, android-listview

Here is the getView function in my adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ResultItem item;
        final TextView fn;
        final View rd;
        item = list.get(position);

        convertView = new RelativeLayout(mContext);

        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(COLOR_RESULT_ENTRY1);
        } else {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(COLOR_RESULT_ENTRY2);
        }

        convertView.setMinimumHeight(ENTRY_MINIMUM_HEIGHT);

        layoutEntry(convertView, parent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        fn = new TextView(mContext);
        fn.setTextSize(GENERIC_TEXT_SIZE);
        fn.setText(item.fieldName);
        layoutItem(fn, (int) (parent.getWidth() * FIELD_NAME_WIDTH), RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0, 0);

        if (item.type == TYPE1) {
            rd = new EditText(mContext);
            ((EditText) rd).setTextSize(GENERIC_TEXT_SIZE);
            ((EditText) rd).setText((String) item.retrievedData);
            ((EditText) rd).setBackgroundDrawable(null);

            rd.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                    if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                        item.retrievedData = ((EditText) rd).getText().toString();
                    }

                    return false;
                }

            });

        } else if (item.type == TYPE2) {
            rd = new TextView(mContext);
            ((TextView) rd).setTextSize(GENERIC_TEXT_SIZE);
            ((TextView) rd).setText((String) item.retrievedData);

            rd.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    if (((TextView) rd).getText().toString().equals(ResultItem.checked)) {
                        ((TextView) rd).setText(ResultItem.unchecked);
                        item.retrievedData = ResultItem.unchecked;
                    } else {
                        ((TextView) rd).setText(ResultItem.checked);
                        item.retrievedData = ResultItem.checked;
                    }

                    return true;
                }

            });

        } else if (item.type == TYPE3) {
            rd = new TextView(mContext);
            ((TextView) rd).setTextSize(GENERIC_TEXT_SIZE);
            ((TextView) rd).setText((String) item.retrievedData);
        } else if (item.type == TYPE4) {
            rd = new ImageView(mContext);
            ((ImageView) rd).setImageBitmap((Bitmap) item.retrievedData);
        } else {
            rd = new TextView(mContext);
            ((TextView) rd).setText((String) item.retrievedData);
        }

        layoutItem(rd, (int) (parent.getWidth() * (1.0f - FIELD_NAME_WIDTH)), 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int) (parent.getWidth() * FIELD_NAME_WIDTH), 0);

        ((RelativeLayout) convertView).addView(fn);
        ((RelativeLayout) convertView).addView(rd);

        return convertView;
    }
```

list is an ArrayList that holds the data that I want to put on a ListView. LayoutEntry and LayoutItem are just two functions that set the view width, height and positions. Basically there are four types of entries that I want to return based on the type field of item.

The weird thing is when I click on the list entry corresponding to TYPE2 and TYPE4, the background color of the entry turned. Actually it is taking a click effect. However, for TYPE4 I didn't implement any clicklistener, for TYPE2 the listener is for rd, not for convertView. If I click on the entry returned by TYPE1 and TYPE3, nothing happens, which is what I expected. Why the weird thing is happening on TYPE2 and TYPE4?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I got you you have custom ListView so you should have custom XML which describes list item. I think you need to look closer to your xml.